# Radio Commands in ToolBar

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I'm building a plugin that display images with some exclusive style.
Think something like you've got an colour image, and you can choose style "Black and white" or "Sepia" etc..

My plugin is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            categoryId="fr.comp.app.category"
            defaultHandler="fr.comp.common.styles.impl.DefaultStyle"
            id="fr.comp.common.styles.defaultStyle"
            name="Default Style">
         <state
               class="org.eclipse.ui.handlers.RadioState"
               id="org.eclipse.ui.commands.radioState">
         </state>
      </command>
      <command
            categoryId="fr.comp.app.category"
            defaultHandler="fr.comp.common.styles.impl.SepiaStyle"
            id="fr.comp.common.styles.SepiaStyle"
            name="Print Style">
         <state
               class="org.eclipse.ui.handlers.RadioState"
               id="org.eclipse.ui.commands.radioState">
         </state>
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
      <key
            commandId="fr.comp.common.styles.defaultStyle"
            contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"
            schemeId="fr.comp.app.scheme"
            sequence="F1">
      </key>
      <key
            commandId="fr.comp.common.styles.SepiaStyle"
            contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"
            schemeId="fr.comp.app.scheme"
            sequence="F6">
      </key>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar">
         <toolbar
               id="fr.comp.app.style.toolbar">
            <command
                  commandId="fr.comp.common.styles.defaultStyle"
                  icon="resources/default.png"
                  style="radio">
            </command>
            <command
                  commandId="fr.comp.common.styles.SepiaStyle"
                  icon="resources/sepia.png"
                  style="radio">
            </command>
         </toolbar>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

My Handlers execute look like this:

```
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

    // blabla change the style 
    final IStyleManager styleManager = MagicHub.getService(IStyleManager.class);
    // ... end blabla

    // change the state of the org.eclipse.ui.commands.radioState of the cmd
    Command command = event.getCommand();
    State state = command.getState(RadioState.STATE_ID);
    state.setValue(Boolean.TRUE);

    return null;
}
```

Ok, now I've got a nice toolbar, that display my commands.
I can click them, and the style apply.
I can use my keybinding too, and the style apply too.

But, when I use keybinding, radios button is not toggle properly.
What am I doing wrong ?

BTW: my target platform is Kepler.